# Instruments Usage Error : Specified target process is invalid:

Tags: ios, instruments, ui-automation

I'm running a test from the command line with UIAutomation and Instruments but have just got this error.

```
Instruments Usage Error : Specified target process is invalid: /path/to/app
instruments, version 6.1 (56160)
```

Restarting the iPhone simulator, Instruments and Xcode seems to fix the problem but it would be good to understand the problem and work out an easier / quicker fix.

Comment: You can provide the name of an app or the full path. Not sure why this is occurring but make sure you provide the absolute path, or if the app is already on your simulator just provide the name of the app without .app appended

Comment: I´m having the same problem. Starting a second time makes it work, but I don´t think this is the correct behavior

Comment: Especially because i'm trying this on travis ci, where I can't save any state (which is good) I can't restart anything